# What happens when you run out of cards

Tags: hearthstone

What happens when all the cards of your deck have been drawn in Hearthstone?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Any time that you're forced to draw an additional card, when there are none left to draw, your hero will experience [**Fatigue**](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Fatigue) damage instead of getting a card.

Fatigue damage starts out at one and increases by one every time it triggers again, i.e. one damage the first time, two damage the second time, and so forth.

When cards get moved back to your stack after you have exhausted it once, you will not get damage for successfully drawing a card, but the Fatigue counter will not be reset.

Comment: It might be a little unclear that "attempting to draw" actually fails and none of you cards, even discarded (pun intended), will never return to the deck in a given game.

Comment: I thought it was clear from the question and having "exhaustet your deck", but I'll I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I understand, but if there was ways to get cards back to the deck, the exhaustion of the deck would depend on such hypothetical ways. Good answer.

Comment: I've removed the first half-sentence and think it's even better now. :)

Comment: Getting cards back to your deck is not purely hypothetical: When [Malorne](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/12293-malorne) dies he's returned to your deck, and [Iron Juggernaut](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/12295-iron-juggernaut) puts a card into the opponent's deck.

Comment: What happens when you get decked?  Usually a horrible death follows.

Comment: Concise and informative!  +1 for the stuff about cards moving back into the stack, which I did not know.